# How to parse date and display as UTC?

Tags: javascript, datetime, datetime-format, utc

I have this code in my existing web application.

```
return format(new Date(date), f);
```

`date: string`

I need to make sure the format is UTC all the time, how do I do that ?

I've tried

```
 return format(new Date(Date.UTC(date), f));
```

But I got errors.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: `format(new Date(Date.UTC(date), f))`: It looks like you have a typo. You are providing `f` as the second argument to the `Date` constructor, when I think it belongs as an argument to your `format` function. Like this instead: `format(new Date(Date.UTC(date)), f)`

Comment: UTC is a time standard, not a format. You might mean ISO 8601 format, but there is more than one of those.

Comment: @jsejcksn—perhaps, but `Date.UTC(date)` doesn't make sense. *ToNumber* is called on each argument, the first is treated as *year* so if `ToNumber(date)` actually returns a number it will be treated as a year, however I suspect it returns *NaN*, so *Date.UTC* will also return *NaN* and `new Date(NaN)` creates an invalid date. So even if the format part is fixed, the rest looks broken anyway.

Answer (score 0):

date.UTC method doesn't accept a date as parameter. Here are some examples of how you should pass the parameters

```
Date.UTC(year)
Date.UTC(year, month)
Date.UTC(year, month, day)
Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour)
Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute)
Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)
```

Comment: This is a comment, it's not an answer. The OP says *date* is a string in "UTC format" by which I assume they mean ISO 8601 format like "YYYY-MM-DD", and passing a string in that format to *Date.UTC* will return *NaN*.